# Windows Admin Center cannot connect to destination

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-admin-center

I am pulling my hair on this.. Can't seem to point a finger at where it went wrong. All error messages are cryptic, and leads to wrong problem.

I have just installed Windows admin Center to one of my server. I already have PS Remoting working for sometimes, and I can enter my servers using `enter-pssession`.

After installation, I tried to connect to the computer where I installed the Windows Admin Center and greeted with this screen.

[image: Wrong Password]

Then I scoured Event Viewer, and found this one

> 400 - CimException: The client cannot connect to the destination
>   specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination
>   is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and
>   documentation for the WS-Management service running on the
>   destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the
>   WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze
>   and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".  Stack trace:
>   at
>   Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Internal.Operations.CimAsyncObserverProxyBase`1.ProcessNativeCallback(OperationCallbackProcessingContext
>   callbackProcessingContext, T currentItem, Boolean moreResults,
>   MiResult operationResult, String errorMessage, InstanceHandle
>   errorDetailsHandle)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementExperience.Cim.CimProxy.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<Query>b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementExperience.Cim.CimProxy.<>c__DisplayClass22_0`1.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementExperience.Security.ImpersonationManager.d__0`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementExperience.Cim.CimProxy.<RunInCimSession>d__22`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementExperience.Cim.CimProxy.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementExperience.FrontEnd.Controllers.FeatureController.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.ManagementExperience.FrontEnd.Handlers.ImpersonationActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

So I checked my WinRM service, and found out it is indeed, running
[image: WinRM Check]

and accepting conneections. Invoke commands is also working properly

[image: Powershell Connection]

The rdp server that I was trying to connect, is the one hosting Windows Admin Center. So it is basically logging in into localhost. The system is freshly installed, and is connected to active directory.

Any idea on where it went wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Ok.. It is solved.

Remove the Windows Admin Center, and reinstall it. This time, remove the checkmark from WinRM https.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answer, try running this commands in Administrator PowerShell window in your server, to get sure everything is well setup:

```
winrm qc
Enable-psremoting
```

And there is another reason that can be tricky: get sure that both the server and the WAC machine have the correct date and time. If there is a mismatch, it can avoid the connection.

NOTE: the firewall, by default, allows connections only from the same subnet.